# Error message when running a Sinatra application on Windows Vista

Tags: ruby, web-applications, sinatra

I was following a video tutorial by Adam Keys about how to make a URL shortener app in Sinatra. The code that is giving me problems is located here http://pastie.org/958644

So when I ran it I got this error:

**shortener.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting $end @@ home**

I typed it exactly as Adam said but this keeps happening. What could the issue be?

By the way, I am running *ruby 1.9.1p243 (2009-07-16 revision 24175) [i386-mingw32]* on Windows Vista.

Thanks,
*Adam*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer on IRC *#sinatra* channel. The problem was two fold.

1. I had a space after **@@ home**. Once I got rid of that space I got a new error.
2. The new error was:

**shortener.rb:8:in : undefined method `use_in_file_templates!' for main:O
bject (NoMethodError)**

The reason this was happening because the video tutorial I was watching was dated and Sinatra is currently at version 1.0. So the updates for Sinatra are located at:

http://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/1.0/CHANGES#L101

Ultimately I just had to replace the **use_in_file_templates!** method with the **enable :inline_templates** method.